# Transferring data from a JSON file to a list item c #

Tags: c#, json, list, rest

I want to put the JSON data in a list to show records to the user. But when I run the system the list only shows the project name twice, and not the JSON data.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("Http://www.eletrotechautomacoes.com.br");
        string url = string.Format("/pontos/consulta.php");
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        List<ExchangeRates> listaProdutos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ExchangeRates>>(result);

        this.LlistSpecials.ItemsSource = listaProdutos;
```

what system shows on the list is the project name appearing twice.

File JSON:

```
[{"id":"1","nome":"pendrive","preco":"20.00","tipo":"eletronico"},{"id":"2","nome":"Monitor","preco":"250.00","tipo":"eletronicos"}]
```

Object:

```
 public class ExchangeRates 
{

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nome")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("preco")]
    public string Preco { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("tipo")]
    public string Tipo { get; set; }


}
```

Thank you all for your help. But even applying the correction continues not funcinando. I think the problem is that part: this.LlistSpecials.ItemsSource = listaProdutos; My difficulty is to show the contents in the list. I need to do some conversion to the list to be shown? They know a procedure to display this list? It is currently returning the project name twice. I think it has something to do with the amount of JSON items, which are two as well.

Comment: @AnuradhS why and how would that help? Isn't HttpClient the successor of WebClient and with that the preferred class to use in new developments?

Comment: why is your property `id` is `List<string>`? due to your json, it may be `string` and then can desalinize.

Comment: If you've defined `id` as `List<string>` then JSON should be `"id":["1"]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Change you `ExchangeRates` class as given below, as `Id` will be a `string` not a `list<string>`.

```
public class ExchangeRates
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string nome { get; set; }
    public string preco { get; set; }
    public string tipo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. But even applying the correction continues not funcinando. I think the problem is that part: this.LlistSpecials.ItemsSource = listaProdutos; My difficulty is to show the contents in the list. I need to do some conversion to the list to be shown?

They know a procedure to display this list?

It is currently returning the project name twice. I think it has something to do with the amount of JSON items, which are two as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know how should look your model, You can use this [online generator](http://json2csharp.com/)

Your model look like this:

```
public class ExchangeRates
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string preco { get; set; }
        public string tipo { get; set; }
    }
```

Update Your model and it should be work.